# Как нарисовать "пустотелый" треугольник в qt?

Tags: qt, qpainter

Как **правильно** нарисовать треугольник  в qt ?

я могу нарисовать его двумя вариантами:

первый вариант

```
// Start point of bottom line
qreal startPointX1 = 60.0;
qreal startPointY1 = 60.0;

// End point of bottom line
qreal endPointX1   = 60.0;
qreal endPointY1   = 120.0;

// Start point of top line
qreal startPointX2 = 60.0;
qreal startPointY2 = 60.0;

// End point of top line
qreal endPointX2   = 80.0;
qreal endPointY2   = 120.0;

QPainterPath path;
// Set pen to this point.
path.moveTo (startPointX2, startPointY2);
// Draw line from pen point to this point.
path.lineTo (endPointX1, endPointY1);

//path.moveTo (endPointX1, endPointY1); // <- no need to move
path.lineTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2);

//path.moveTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2); // <- no need to move
path.lineTo (startPointX1, startPointY1);

QPainter painter(this);
painter.setPen (Qt :: NoPen);
painter.fillPath (path, QBrush (QColor ("blue")));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Второй более предпочтительней :

```
    QRectF rect = QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100);

    QPainterPath path;
    path.moveTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft());
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight());
    path.lineTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.fillPath(path, QBrush(QColor ("blue")));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот весь код последней версии в которую поставил фотографию :

**treygol.pro**

```
QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = treygol
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

DISTFILES += \
    treygol.jpg
```

**mainwindows.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QRectF>
#include <QKeyEvent>

struct texnStructur
{
    texnStructur() // сразу же заполняем его нулями
    {
        m_pitch = 0;    m_t_pitch = 0;   razm_lin = 0;   razm_text = 0;
        razm_shrift = 0;    razm_stroki = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < sizeof(m_t_razm)/ sizeof(m_t_razm[0]); i++)
            m_t_razm[i] = 0;
    }

    float m_t_razm[5];

    int  m_t_pitch;    // техническая переменная
    int  m_pitch; // переменная для положения на градусной ленте
    float razm_lin; // переменная размера градулированной линии копаса
    float razm_text; // переменная размера текста (цифр) копаса

    int razm_shrift; // переменная размера шрифта текста копаса
    int razm_stroki;
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
     void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
//     void resizeEvent/*(*/QResizeEvent *event);
     void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);


     texnStructur _myTexpr; // обьявляем его
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindows.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    QRectF rect = QRectF(190, 0, 500, 400);
    QPixmap img("treygol.jpg");


    QPainterPath path;

    path.moveTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft());
    path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight());
    path.lineTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());

    QPainter painter(this);

    QPen pen_abris(Qt::black, 5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap); // кисть абриса (компаса)

    painter.setPen(QPen(pen_abris));

    QBrush br (Qt::SolidPattern,img);
    painter.setBrush(br);

     painter.drawPath(path);
}


void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        //            _myTexpr.m_pitch++;
        _myTexpr.m_pitch += 1.0;
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        //            _myTexpr.m_pitch--;
        _myTexpr.m_pitch -= 1.0;
        break;

    default:
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
        break;
    }

    update();
}
```

**Вот так вот**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почитал о том что QBrush Можно сделать что был треугольник с обводами "пустотелый".
Но как я не пытался QBrush настроить так мне и не удалось :(**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ух разобрался :)

Надо было в `mainwindow.h`добавить строку `#include <QBrush>`

вот код из `mainwindow.cpp` :

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

     QRectF rect = QRectF(190, 0, 500, 400);

     QPainterPath path;

     path.moveTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());
     path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft());
     path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight());
     path.lineTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());

     QPainter painter(this);
      QPen pen(Qt::green, 3, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
      painter.setPen(pen);

      QBrush br (Qt::NoBrush);
      painter.setBrush(br);

      painter.drawPath(path);
}
```

вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]